# Para que sirve anaconda

Tags: python, r, data, anaconda, datos

Me estoy iniciando en el mundo de los datos y no entiendo muy bien para qué sirve Anaconda. Esta app te deja instalar Visual Studio Code, RStudio, Spyder, pero son herramientas que tú mismo puedes instalar sin necesidad de usar Anaconda. Además de que si tienes por ejemplo Visual Studio Code instalado en tu ordenador, en Anaconda te sale otra vez para instalar, con lo que acabas con 2 Visual Studio Code.

¿Alguien me podría explicar un poco?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda es una distribución de Python, que incluye muchos paquetes. En principio, tu sistema operativo no tiene porqué traer instalado Python. Aún si lo trajera, el cómo instalar o configurar un paquete para Python puede no ser tan obvio; no siempre se reduce a descargar un archivo o un ejecutable. Lo que hace Anaconda es incluir toda una distribución con paquetes populares, y un repositorio desde donde instalar estos y otros muchos paquetes. Esto conlleva facilidad para su instalación (sólo se requieren unas líneas en la consola para instalar el paquete adecuado), una relativa garantía de que las dependencias (paquetes que se requieren para ejecutar otros) estén en las versiones correctas, y evita la búsqueda dispersa de dichas dependencias. Si bien todo lo podrías hacer "a mano", el que esté en un sistema unificado puede hacer más sencillas las cosas.